# How can I correctly test my App component to verify that the routes are rendering the correct components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, enzyme

In my App component, I have a bunch of routes that render their respective components and I want to test that the routes are rendering the correct components.

**App.js**

```
export default () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
            
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
                    <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

After reading some stuff on the internet and following some tuts I understand that I can use MemoryRouter to check if a certain component match with a given route, and if it does it should return one or length value 1.

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {  mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';

import App from './App';
import { Home } from './home/Home';
import Signup from './auth/signup/Signup';
import Signin from './auth/signin/Signin';

describe('routes using memory router', () => {
    it('should show <Home /> component for "/" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}><App /></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Home)).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('should show <Signup /> component for "/signup" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/signup"]}><App /></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Signup)).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('should show <Signin /> component for "/signin" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/signin"]}><App /></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Signin)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

But totally unexpected I got this error, saying that it couldn't find the store. The message repeats 3 times, for the three routes i am trying to test, "/", "/signup" and "/signin". I just copied the 3rd message here.

```
 Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter())". Either wrap the root component
 in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(withRouter())
 in connect options.

      23 |
      24 |     it('should show <Signin /> component for "/signin" route', () => {
    > 25 |         const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/signin"]}><App /></MemoryRouter>);
         |                           ^
      26 |
      27 |         expect(component.find(Signin)).toHaveLength(1);
      28 |     });
```

Based on the above approach how can I correctly test to see if the routes render the correct components? I should mention that this is my first time testing so I am trying to learn. I apologise if something is unclear in my question. Any answer or link or even another approach will be greatly appreciated.

**The new error after solving the store problem**

```
● renders correct routes › should show <Signup /> component for "/signup" route

    expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

    Expected length: 1
    Received length: 0
    Received object: {}

      40 |         );
      41 |
    > 42 |         expect(wrapper.find(Signup)).toHaveLength(1);
         |                                      ^
      43 |     });
      44 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/App.test.js:42:38)
```

I get this message for all routes that I am testing, I pasted here only one of them, they are all the same, except for different routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the provider along with the store.
Add changes to your **App.test.js**
*Like here:*

```
import React from 'react';
import {  mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './App';
import { Home } from './home/Home';
import Signup from './auth/signup/Signup';
import rootReducer from './reducer';

describe('routes using memory router', () => {
    let store
    beforeEach(async () => {
        store = createReduxStore(
            rootReducer,
        )
    })

    it('should show <Home /> component for "/" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Home)).toHaveLength(1);
      });

    it('should show <Signup /> component for "/signup" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/signup"]}><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Signup)).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it('should show <Signin /> component for "/signin" route', () => {
        const component = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/signin"]}><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></MemoryRouter>);

        expect(component.find(Signin)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

**For new issue:**

Instead of wrapping the component with your provider, use the `wrappingComponent` option, like this:

```
function WrapWithProviders({ children }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Switch>
          {children}
        </Switch>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent />, {
  wrappingComponent: WrapWithProviders,
});
```

but i'm not sure, about this

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I followed your suggestion and it solved the store issue, but now I get something new. I will update my question above with the error I get, maybe you have an idea about what that is about.

Comment: @TarasiCristiAndrei I added some more info in the answer

Comment: Amazing. It actually worked. Thank you, my friend. And it worked without Switch. After I saw your solution worked, I started reading more about mount method, but I still dont know what that second argument(object) is.